# 404 usage with router and different routing files

Tags: node.js

I use in my app different routes. All this routes have a topic file. Like:

- index.js -> for basic routing in the / level. Like /welcome or
  /dashboard
- cases.js -> for using edit forms Like /cases/case_create
- tcafe.js -> for testing routes like /tcafe/startit
- users.js -> for user operation like /users/login or /users/register

In my app I use:

```
// Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index.js'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users.js'));
app.use('/cases', require('./routes/cases.js'));
app.use('/tcafe', require('./routes/tcafe.js'));
```

Ok, now I want to add a 404 handler so I can avoid "Cannot GET /dashboard2"

I added now to the end of all route files:

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    next({
        status: 404,
        message: 'Not Found',
    });
});

router.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err.status === 404) {
        return res.status(400).render('404');
    }

    if (err.status === 500) {
        return res.status(500).render('500');
    }

    next();
});
```

now I get a 404 if using "/dashboard2" but all other routes also get a 404
like "/users/login" or "/cases/create_case"

Moving the code to the main js file (server.js) also do not work.

Anybody has a Idea how to protect the whole app with 404 for all routes?

Comment: Have you tried adding `app.use((req, res, next) => res.status(404).send('Not found, boy'));` after all of the `app.use()` above? (note, that I don't use `router.use()`, but `app.use()`)

Comment: Not all but your comment solved the problem. I have to added the code after the block with the routes. Many thanks :-)

Comment: Glad, I could help, posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the official [Express FAQ](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html):

> All you need to do is add a middleware function at the very bottom of the stack (below all other functions) to handle a 404 response

So in your case, you need to put your 404-handler after all of the `router.use()` calls.